# GIF freezes on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to show a GIF as a sort of loading screen, between 2 pages. 
But as soon as I click the link, to go to the next page, the GIF freezes.
As if the browser stops any processes other than loading.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the relevant code so we can see.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. We will need more informations in order to help you. First we would need the code you are using to implement the GIF. Also, Is the gif already shown before the click on a link ? Are you using an SPA, or do you just want to load the GIF first while the rest of the page is loading ?

Comment: The GIF has an opacity of 0, and margin-top: -30vh; to get it out of the way. Then when the button is pressed, the GIF is centered in middle of the screen and the opacity is set to 1. So yes, the GIF is already there, and isn't loaded when the button is pressed.
I've tried to have it on screen also, and then tested it, but as soon as I hit the button the GIF stops.

Comment: It works in Chrome but not Safari

Comment: Although it's on Firefox, maybe it will help you: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/952482

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an interesting thing I learned a while ago. The gifs loaded, are animated on the main thread, the same one used by JavaScript. Once the page unloading begins your animation will stop. Your best bet in this situation is to use CSS animations, as they run on a separate thread. Under different circumstances, you would want to use a web worker or something similar to prevent page lockup.

Comment: It's something like that I feared. Thanks for your answer tho :)